# Turn pandas DataFrame with two columns into stacked barplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

My data (in a pandas DataFrame) looks like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"age" : [25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 27, 27, 25, 26, 26, 25, 25],
                  "category" : [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2]})
```

I want a stacked barplot - each bar should reflect how many are in an age group and what percentage within the agegroup belongs to which category. The code

```
a.pivot_table('category', 'age').plot(kind='bar')
```

returns only the mean of the category instead of stacking it the way I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do something like the following... You need to change the aggregating function in `pivot_table` (which defaults to 'mean') and then use `stacked=True` when you plot:

```
table = a.pivot_table(index='category', columns='age', aggfunc='size')
table.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This yields:

[image]